# In Laravel (5.3), how do I perform a loop through two separate DB tables and send the results into a view?

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-5.3

I am VERY new to Laravel, so please bear with me if this is a stupid question.

Here is ultimately what I am trying to do.

I have two database tables: Categories and FoodItems. Let's say for simplicities sake, that I have two categories in the Categories table (Appetizers, and Sandwiches), and I have 3 items in the FoodItems table:

- Onion Rings, which has a foreign key pointing to the Appetizers table
- Mozzarella Sticks, which has a foreign key pointing to the Appetizers table
- Hamburger, which has a foreign key pointing to the Sandwiches table

I have a view, where I want to first display all of the categories, and then show all of the items in that category.

So my view would display:

Appetizers:
- Onion Rings
- Mozzarella Sticks

Sandwiches:
- Hamburger

I can't figure out how I could loop through these two tables, do a nested DB call, and then send this structure into my view, without doing any of the logic actually inside the view.

Could anybody please tell me what the best practice here would be, to get the data, as I have it ordered, into my view?

**Edits/Extra Info:**

Just to let everybody know where I am at (I am still struggling). Here is all of my code.

First, I have two database tables set up. The first is called "**foodItems**" and the second is called "**foodCategories**".

The **foodItems** table has the following columns:
id, uniqueID, categoryID, clientID, itemName, itemDescription, itemAlias, thumbURL, itemSize, itemCost, itemPrice, isTaxable, hasSizes, hasDescriptors, status, created_at, updated_at

The **foodCategories** table has the following columns:
id, uniqueID, clientID, categoryName, categoryAlias, status, created_at, updated_at

Next, I have two models, **FoodItem**, and **FoodCategory**.

The code I have in my **FoodItem** model looks like so:

```
    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

     class FoodItem extends Model {
            protected $table = 'foodItems';

          public function foodCategory(){
                 return $this->belongsTo('App\FoodCategory');
            }
     }
```

The code in my **FoodCategory** model looks like so:

```
<?php
    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class FoodCategory extends Model {
        protected $table = 'foodCategories';

        public function foodItem() {
                return $this->hasMany('App\FoodItem');
        }
    }
```

The code in my controller looks like this:

```
<?php
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\FoodCategory;
    use App\FoodItem;

    class DashboardController extends Controller {

        public function __construct(){
            $this->middleware('auth');
        }

        public function food() {
            $food_items = FoodItem::orderBy('categoryID')->get();
            return view('food', compact('food_items'));
        }
    }
```

And finally, the code I have in my View (food.blade.php) is:

```
@foreach ($food_items as $food)
    <li>{{ $food->foodCategory->categoryName }}</li>
@endforeach
```

In my view, I have tried using parenthesis after "**foodCategory**", I have tried changing the name to "FoodCategory", "FoodCategory()", "foodCategories()", "foodCategories"... and about every other combination I can think of - but nothing seems to work.

As the code is right now, it produces the following error:

"Trying to get property of non-object (View: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Laravel/ChanceSystems2017/resources/views/food.blade.php)"

I'm really stumped at this point. Could anybody please shed some light onto what I am missing? Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/7

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be solved by using relationships. Follow this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships) for more information

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oPc5ijQXq2s&index=37&list=PLwAKR305CRO-Q90J---jXVzbOd4CDRbVx) helped me a lot in understanding relationships in laravel. Hope it helps you too.

Comment: Thank you for providing me with this resource @Dipesh. I followed along as best as I could, and have made edits to my original question based on this video. This might give you a bit more information to help me debug a bit further.

Comment: You need to select data from foodCategories table too. And send it to view. Then only your code in view will work.